# jquery slidetoggle() not hiding :before element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All of my elements hide and show correctly using `slidetoggle()`, EXCEPT for my `li:before`. I've tried forcing the overflow, visibility, display, etc on the `:before` and the `li`, and nothing is helping, it still shows the bullets set using the `:before` class. What needs to happen to hide these bullets when `slidetoggle()` is activated/deactivated?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#read-more").click(function(){
            $(".careers-position").slideToggle(800);
    return false;
        });
    });
```

```css
ul {
        line-height: 2.4em !important;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding: 0 0 23px 1em;
        }
        li {
        list-style: none !important;
        color: #656565;
    }
    li:before {
        content: "";
        background: #9e9e9e;
        width: 6px;
        height: 6px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 18px;
        margin-top: 16px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
   .careers-position {
     display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="careers-position">
    <h3>Pilot</h3>
    Position information will go here.
    We are an equal opportunity employer and all qualified applicants will receive consideration for employment. 
    <strong>Requirements:</strong>
    <ul>
      <li>Multi Commercial (ATP preferred)</li>
      <li>First Class Medical</li>
      <li>Passport</li>
      <li>90 day currency</li>
      <li>Clean FAA record</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="careers-read-more">
     <a class="quick-btn" id="read-more" href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add position relative:

```css
.careers-position {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/joqimu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I was actually able to resolve this by changing up some of the CSS for li:before. By changing the position to relative and adjusting the margin's so that they are shown properly next to the list item, this fixed it :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wfccp58p/4/

`ul { line-height: 2.4em; margin-left: 20px;padding: 0 0 23px 1em;list-style-type: none;}`

I removed the li:before and added the list-style-type to the ui.  Not sure if you still wanted some of the LI:Before pseudo stuff, but this fixes your issue.